# How to persist data of vuejs SPA in android webview?

Tags: android, vue.js, webview, nuxt.js, persistent-storage

I have a web app built with Nuxt JS a Vue js framework. I want to show my web app to android app's `webview`.

I have used local-storage and persisted data using vue-persistent-state so that even if I refresh the page, the data will be persistent.

Will this work on android `webview`?

I have read on DOM storage api. Not sure if it's the same thing I am asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use **local-storage** in **webview**

Just set following setting in your android project:

`webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true)`

Answer (score 0):

You can consider a webview as a browser. So yes, `local-storage` work in `webview` as well.